# mongodb in codeigniter, debug problem

Tags: codeigniter, mongodb

in some_code.php

---

```
$query = new MongoCode('
    function (index, value){
        .... 
         // I need to check some value of some_variable in here
         // etc ) some_variable = 1 or "abc"
        ....
    }
');
$run = $this->db->command($query);
```

---

How could I print mongodb variables in php?

Answer (score 1):

`var_dump()` is always your friend.